# Sinon stub a internal function of a function

Tags: javascript, sinon

I have a local function within a function and I want to stub it. Basically it is the end function which updates data, but i don't want it to run.

```
//js file
module.exports.mainFunc = function() {
  function secondaryFunc() {
    function dontWantThisToRun() {
    }
  }
};

//test file
const mainFunc = require().mainFunc;
let sandbox;
sandbox.dontWantThisToRun = sinon.stub(mainFunc, "dontWantThisToRun").callsFake(())
```

And if I can not do it with sinon. Is it anyhow I can overwrite it in my test?
Thank you a lot. Any idea is appreciated.